# Newly installed tensorflow_cpu version 2.2 throws error when trying to import

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pip, tensorflow2.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Amex\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Did you install Tensorflow with `conda` or by `pip` ?

Comment: i did installed with pip

Comment: Try using `conda install tensorflow`. It runs on a machine without AVX.

Comment: thanks ..it works when i try verifying the installation on the terminal ,but throws error when i try calling it in my notebook